# Does Erlang's open_port call link to resulting process?

Tags: erlang

I've got some C code that I'm executing as an external process using Erlang's Port capability.  I want the process that starts the C code, via `open_port`, to detect if the C code crashes. The documentation isn't completely clear to me, but as I understand it, a two-way link is established between the Erlang process and the external code. If one dies, the other is notified.

Here is a slightly modified version of the code in the "Erlang Interoperability Tutorial Guide" (http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_port.html):

```
init(ExtPrg) ->
    register(cport, self()),
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    Port = open_port({spawn, ExtPrg}, [{packet, 2}]),
    PInfo = erlang:port_info(Port),
    io:format("Port: ~p   PInfo: ~p~n", [Port, PInfo]),
    RVal = link(Port),
    io:format("link?  ~p~n", [RVal]),
    loop(Port).

loop(Port) ->
    receive
        {call, Caller, Msg} ->
            Port ! {self(), {command, encode(Msg)}},
            receive
                {Port, {data, Data}} -> 
                    Caller ! {cport, decode(Data)}
            end,
            loop(Port);
        stop ->
            Port ! {self(), close},
            receive
                {Port, closed} -> 
                    exit(normal)
            end;
        {'EXIT', Port, Reason} -> 
            exit(port_terminated)
    end.
```

The `init` call correctly executes the C code, and as you can see sets `trap_exit`, but the `EXTT` message is not received when I kill the C code using `kill -HUP` from the Unix shell.  I've tried with and without the `link` call (the Erlang documentation does not use it).  The printing code I've added generates:

```
Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
1> cport:start("./cport 22").
Port: #Port<0.630>   PInfo: [{name,"./cport 22"},
                             {links,[<0.38.0>]},
                             {id,630},
                             {connected,<0.38.0>},
                             {input,0},
                             {output,0}]
<0.38.0>
link?  true
```

It appears that a link is registered but I'm not catching the trap.  What am I missing?

Comment: try `flush().` after killing port's process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried from within Erlang shell after I killed port's process--just returns ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the extra option exit_status when calling open_port().

I did a similar Erlang program for supervising game servers. 
When the external game server crashed I wanted to restart it from my central Erlang monitoring system.
This was the code that worked for me:

```
erlang:open_port({spawn_executable, "<Path to my game server start script>"}, 
                 [ exit_status ]),
```

When the external process is killed you will get a message of type

```
{Port,{exit_status,Status}}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks.  Works with `spawn` in addition to `spawn_executable`.

Comment: Is there a way to go the other way? If erlang process crashes, kill the opened port?